# How to remove the item in session using javascript for codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am working on a shopping cart php(codeigniter) project. So I have add the item in the session like the code following. The problem is, I would like to remove the item in session in the checkout page.

But of course I can not call the php function to remove the session in javascript , that means , when the remove button is click , how can I do (not restrict to use ajax, simple is the best), I can remove the item in session ? Thanks

```
   if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
                    if ($this->session->userdata('purchase') !== false)
                        $purchase_list = $this->session->userdata('purchase');
                    else
                        $purchase_list = array();

                    $purchase = array(
                        'id' => $product[0]['id'],
                        'quantity' => $this->input->post('quantity')
                    );

                    if ($this->input->post('opt1') !== false)
                        $purchase['opt1'] = $this->input->post('opt1');

                    if ($this->input->post('opt2') !== false)
                        $purchase['opt2'] = $this->input->post('opt2');

                    array_push($purchase_list, $purchase);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('purchase', $purchase_list);
                    redirect('cart');
                }
```

Comment: I think we can not 'not restrict to ajax'. it's pretty much the way to interact with a server with javascript

Comment: because in some website I see they implement it by refreshing the whole page, it is ok for me so I am welcome to all appoarch just refresh the page

Comment: Oh I see, I misunderstood and thought you did want to not refresh the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a function in your controller to unset the session e.g.

```
    class Controllername extends CI_Controller {

    function index(){}

    function reset_session(){
$sesion_variable = 'name_of_session';
    $this->session->unset_userdata($session_variable);
    }

    }
```

And you can call that via CURL or ajax. On checkout page

Answer (score 0):

from CodeIgniter's [session class documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

This assumes you understand your cart and will know where to actually unset session data in your checkout scenery.

you can set the value of desired item in your session using this syntax:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('purchase', null); // will set the purchase session data to null
```

you only know which key to set to null though

Comment: thanks the key of the question is how to use javascript , say the onclick event to call the php setnull function

Comment: please clarify your question (by editing it). You say you do not mind refreshing the page but you also say you want to use javascript. You say you want to use javascript but post a code sample in php. Why not just use a `<a>` tag like a normal link?

Comment: Using the onclick event to call php is called **ajax**. either you use **ajax** with javascript events, or you use a normal link, and the code here applies